# Photo disappearing when screen is minimized using media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I created a webpage with a 2x2 photo grid.  I have used media queries to turn the photos into a 1x4 grid when the screen is less than 1300 pixels wide.  The problem is that one of the top right photo disappears when I minimize the screen.  It happens between 600px and 1300px.

Here's the codepen:  http://codepen.io/queenlizo/full/bEvQRJ/

These are the media queries in question:

```
.center-row > div > p,
    .center-row > div > ul {
    display: block;
 }

.center-row > div {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display: table-cell;
  border:0;
  color:#fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .center-row > div:hover > p,
  .center-row > div:hover > ul,
  .center-row > div:hover > h2 {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1300px)  {

  .center-row > div {
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       display: table-cell;
       border: 0;
       color:#fff;
       vertical-align: middle;
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get rid of the `all and` in the @media. All is the default and `and` isn't needed since you're not joining anything.

Should be written as below:
`@media (max-width: 1300px)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In `.center-row` remove:

```
display: table-row;
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works, but then the pictures dont display correctly in Firefox.  I'll play around with it some more.  Thanks for getting me on the right track.